# Order of exception handling stack frames on the call stack

Tags: .net, exception, callstack

What is the order in which exception handling stack frames are pushed onto the call stack in say C#. If i have a method:

```
private void MyMethod() {
  try {
    DoSomething();  
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Handle
  }
}
```

Is a separate stack frame created for each exception handler as follows?

```
DoSomething stackframe<br/>
Exception stackframe<br/>
MyMethod stackframe<br/>
```

OR

```
DoSomething stackframe<br />
MyMethod stackframe<br />
Exception stackframe<br />
```

OR

something else?

Comment: You can try this for yourself. Create an application with the code you want to test, and then step through it in the debugger, examining the call stack at each step. I guess it's the same for all languages once they're MSIL, but they may be different in what MSIL code they emit for certain language constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, adding an exception handler doesn't add a new frame to the call stack. It just adds appropriate information so that when an exception is thrown, at each level of the call stack the framework can find the appropriate handler for that exception (if indeed there *is* an appropriate handler).

It's a little bit like garbage collection, where at any point of execution the GC can work out which local variables should still count as GC roots - essentially there's more to a method than the executable code itself :)

Comment: O.k. so I've misread a wikipedia article. So if DoSomething throws an exception that t doesn't handle, the call stack is unwound and each calling stack frame is examined for an exception handler? Is there anything particularly special about the way exception handler info is included in the stack frame... as opposed to say local variables?

Comment: @intermension: I don't know the details off the top of my head, but "CLR via C#" gives more information, I think.